# Volusion API - Export Orders by Date Range

Tags: volusion

On a scheduled basis, I would like to export Volusion orders by a date range:

```
select * from orders o where o.OrderDate >= '7/20/2015' AND o.OrderDate <= '7/23/2015'
```

Is this possible? It appears my URL can only do an equals sign:

https://www.XX.net/net/WebService.aspx?Login=shopxperts@yahoo.com&EncryptedPassword=XX&EDI_Name=Generic\Orders&SELECT_Columns=*&WHERE_Column=o.orderdate&WHERE_Value=7/18/2015 10:58:09 AM

I looked at the SQL saved query feature. Is there a way to save a query with parameters, then fill them in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can insert parameters into the query and execute it from the Generic folder.

Using a custom ASP page, this is a summary of what you would have to do

1- Read the querystring(s) and sanitizing them.

2- Construct the SQL query with sanitized parameters

3- Write the SQL and XSD files to the "Generic" folder

4- execute the now written file in the generic folder by making a http request

https://www.XX.net/net/WebService.aspx?Login=shopxperts@yahoo.com&EncryptedPassword=XX&EDI_Name=Generic\xyz

5- Delete the files since it's no longer needed once the query is complete.

6- Return data from the query to the page requesting the data

Obviously, this is an very abridged version of what you would need to do but it is certainly possible.