# how to write insert, update and delete queries in volusion

Tags: php, volusion

Here is the order insertion method via SQL query ...

[How to connect Volusion DB without using admin panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37302496/connect-to-volusion-sql-without-using-admin-panel)

I want that how to write insertion SQL query for product. Is it same like the order or different??

Also i am totally confuse that which type of data format is volusion API support?? i am passing XML data.

XSD file is why needed for insertion like in this link ..

https://support.volusion.com/hc/en-us/articles/209638947

There is a lot of Export methods but no perfect and proper Import method via Volusion API.

Anyone knows please help me i have post 3 questions about this issue no can give perfect and correct answer that do good.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use the Volusion API for this?  In other words, does it have to be automated?

In most cases I find myself using the "standard import" and "standard export" feature within the store admin.

Even if I have to prepare the CSV file dynamically, and upload it manually, I prefer this method.

For queries where I have to update or delete many records based on certain criteria, I use the "bulk updates" feature in Volusion.  You will see it in the admin under certain sections.  If you click "Switch to Advanced View" you can run a valid SQL query here ... for example:

```
DELETE FROM Customers WHERE LastName = 'temp'
```

Comment: No no i just want import or insert the products to my store from my vendor site. I will not import it from admin it will automatically. Because I have Developed a web service that get data in json form I convert it to XML then pass to API but the method you post is not work.